# How do I get the actual value from this in Scala : Right(Vector("abc"))

Tags: json, scala, vector, gatling, jsonpath

I'm using Gatling to test a WebSocket based service and in order to parse a json response I get I use the following:

```
val initiator = JsonPath.query("$.header.initiator", json).right.map(_.toVector)
```

Printing initiator tells me that this is :

```
Right(Vector(guest3075085133639688955@example.com))
```

Now to the beginner Scala question:

How do I get the actual string value "guest3075085133639688955@example.com" ?

I've understood that the Right is just a container, that contains a Vector with one value (the value I want), but how do I get to it ?! :)

I've tried this, but that just prints the same thing (Right(Vect....):

```
initiator.foreach{println}
```

Cheers,
Niklas

Answer (score 0):

- You can use `right` to get the `RightProjection` of the `Either` and
  `get` to get the value inside the `Right`.
- You can use `head` to get the first (and in your case only) element from the `Vector`.

Which looks like :

```
val initiator: Either[String, Vector[String]] = 
  Right(Vector("guest3075085133639688955@example.com"))

initiator.right.get.head
// String = guest3075085133639688955@example.com
```

You could also do a pattern match :

```
val Right(Vector(email)) = initiator
// email: String = guest3075085133639688955@example.com
```

Note that both ways only work when `initiatior` is a `Right` and the `Vector` inside has at least one element. Your question is not exactly clear how you would like to handle `Left` and/or an empty `Vector`.

---

If you want to handle all the failing cases in another way, you could use :

```
initiator match {
  case Right(Vector(email)) => email // ok
  case _ => // default -> fail
}
```

Comment: I think that Left and empty Vectors will fail my test case here, and that actually is kinda ok. Anything but the Right(Vector)) I guess could fail a little bit prettier though.

Answer (score 0):

`initiator.right.get` from Either is unsafe. Because it throws an `java.util.NoSuchElementException` if it is a left value.

By pattern matching:

```
initiator match {
  // when it is a right value, which is a vector with single element
  case Right(Vector(s)) => println(s)
  // when it is a right value, which is a vector with empty or two or more elements.
  case Right(v) => ???
  // when it is a left value
  case Left(l) => ???
}
```

Comment: This being a test case scenario means an exception here will fail the test, which is kinda ok. If there is some 'default' for the match I could potentially use that to fail a little prettier.

Answer (score 0):

In acomment you clarified this is for a test case scenario. If you're using ScalaTest matchers you could do:

```
initiator should matchPattern{case Right(Vector("expected value")) => }
```